# Python - %paste

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I am following a tutorial where the teacher pastes in the html inline with our scrappy shell via: `%paste` ( the html below)

```
html_doc = " "
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of hte page </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>H1 Tag</h1>
<h2> H2 Tag with <a href="#">link</a></h2>
<p> First Paragraph </p>
<p>Second Paragraph </p>
</body>
</html>
" "
```

but I get this error:

```
 <html>

  File "<console>", line 1

    <html>


SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have imported tkinter, and looked up other reasources but cant figure out how to get html inline.

Comment: Maybe a keyboard shortcut used with a text expander like [typinator](http://www.ergonis.com/products/typinator/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing `"""`:

```
html_doc = """
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of hte page </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>H1 Tag</h1>
<h2> H2 Tag with <a href="#">link</a></h2>
<p> First Paragraph </p>
<p>Second Paragraph </p>
</body>
</html>
"""
```